# What are the rules for SFTP users?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I have an FTP server that authenticates via an API and has user folders in:

```
/home/ftpusers/files/<username>
```

Some users have requested SFTP instead and since I already have processes in place to put files in the user's directory, I figure I can just create accounts for the users.

```
useradd -g sftpgroup -d /home/ftpusers/files/username/ -s /sbin/nologin username
mkdir -p /home/ftpusers/files/username/.ssh
chown -R username:ftpgroup /home/ftpusers/files/username
chmod -R 770 /home/ftpusers/files/username
echo "ssh-rsa user key" > /home/ftpusers/files/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown username:sftpgroup /home/ftpusers/files/username/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/ftpusers/files/username/.ssh
chown username:sftpgroup /home/ftpusers/files/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/ftpusers/files/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

the ftpgroup is so a system account can place files in the user folder
the sftpgroup is to lock this user to just SFTP using:

```
Match Group sftpgroup
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. No useful error, just:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

It does work fine though if I create a user in a more standard way in the /home/ directory

Any ideas on why? I know chroot has a lot of permission restrictions. Is this something like that?

Added namei output:
Sure thing:

```
namei -l /home/ftpusers/files/jmandel/.ssh
f: /home/ftpusers/files/jmandel/.ssh
dr-xr-xr-x root    root      /
drwxr-xr-x root    root      home
drwxrwx--- ftpuser ftpgroup  ftpusers
drwxrwx--- ftpuser ftpgroup  files
drwxrwx--- jmandel ftpgroup  jmandel
drwx------ jmandel sftpgroup .ssh
```

> **Marked answer below has good information in comment thread**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `sshd_config` file following directive and restart `ssh`:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /home/ftpusers/files/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys
```

This will tell ssh daemon where to look for public keys.

Personally I don't use `authorized_keys` for a long time, but using instead
`AuthorizedKeysCommand` where I call my program that looking in sqlite database user's key and send them back for authentication. This way I prevent users/hackers to use their own keys and such configuration don't disclose place where public keys are located.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but it didn't seem to work

Comment: @Supergibbs Could you add to your question output of: `namei -l /home/ftpusers/files/SomeUserName/.ssh` ?

Comment: Sure thing, added above for better formatting

Comment: Check if user **jmandel** belonging to the group **ftpgroup** by running `id jmandel`

Comment: It's not because I don't want it to, that would allow *jmandel* access to other users folders. There is a user in the *ftpgroup* that places files in various user folders. As a test though, I added *jmandel* to *ftpgroup* and it didn't help

Comment: If users aren't belong to ftpgroup and directory `/home/ftpusers` restricting access to group `other` then how they would travel to their ftp(home) ? Try to set 775 to directories  `/home/ftpusers` and `/home/ftpusers/files` for the test purpose.

Comment: They are the owner of their home directory, do they also need access for the full path? Not a lot of linux admin experience here.

I tried 775 and it didn't work either

Comment: Can you remove temporally public key authentication and try SFTP with plain password ?

Comment: So password worked! But folder permissions did not. Seems like users need permissions for the full path to their home dir. This might not work out the way I need it to. Thanks for all your help! Still not sure why keys aren't working either.

Comment: Figured it out! home directories need to be 700 for key logins (along with .ssh dir and the authorized_keys file needs to be 600). Alternatively, add "StrictModes no" to sshd_config. Thanks for all the help Alex!

Comment: Additionally, I used 771 to allow users access to their home folder but not be able to list /home/ directory. That would expose our client list

Answer (score 0):

Is it really

```
echo "ssh-rsa user key" > /home/ftpusers/files/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

`authorized_keys` contains the public key of the people allowed to log in as this userid, so it's different for each userid you create. In theory the users generate their own public/private key pair and give you the public key. You can of course generate the pair yourself and give them the private part, but if anything bad happens they can claim it was done by someone else using their private key.

Comment: The user provides me with their public key and I use it to create their account